# stream_filter_append php not working in aws server

Tags: php, file, amazon-web-services, upload

the following code for file encryption is working perfectly in my local xampp server. But while uploaded and run in aws ec2 server its not working
`stream_filter_append($fcrypt, 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts)`   code. file is not encrypting. How can i solve this issue?

```
$fin = fopen($input_stream, "rb");
$fcrypt = fopen($aes_filename, 'wb');
$opts = array('iv'=>'','key'=>$key, 'mode'=>'ctr');
if(!stream_filter_append($fcrypt, 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts)){
    echo "encryption failed";
    exit;
}else{
    while (!feof($fin))
    {
        fwrite($fcrypt, fread($fin, 8192));
    }
    fclose($fcrypt);
    fclose($fin);
}
```

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: i need a crypter that will work both in php and android. Which one is best and better?

Answer (score 0):

[RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) is available cross platform and for several languages, it is also complete with random IV, password extension and encryption authentication. It is well vetted under current development and support.

Answer (score 0):

the actual problem of not working my code is related with the stream filter name 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', i just installed 'mcrypt' to my aws server by using the following codes.

```
sudo yum install php56-mcrypt
sudo service httpd restart
```

Now its working perfectly